# Bootstrap Navbar in container but container below is a different size

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I have created a navbar and made it container width by adding .container to the .navbar classes. I have created a new row below but its container is less wide than the navbar. I'm sure I've done something stupid but not sure what

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top container" role="navigation" id="topnavbar">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="assets/newOrangelogo2.svg" width="300"></a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a class="sliding-u-l-r" href="#">About Me</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Process</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Prices</a></li>


                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
              </ul>


            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->  
        </div>
```

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutter">

            <div class="col-md-12 mainImage">
                Image

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Looks the same width to me.  http://www.bootply.com/ipjPSKymxd

Comment: sorry my mistake. I was experimenting with no gutters in columns - a bit of css i found here. I think it cocked things up. Once i took it out all worked fine

Comment: best to answer your own question then, so others don't see this as "unanswered"...